# Hiding ListView Row if Array[Position] is Null

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

Here is the code in the `getView` method of my `Custom ListView Adapter`. It gives me a `NullPointerException`. Can someone explain to my why this is happening? I am trying to inflate a custom listView row called "null_row" if text2 at any position in the array is null.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Holder holder;
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new Holder();

        if (text2[position] != null) {

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailrow, null);

        } else {

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.null_row, null);

        }

        holder.tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.leftside);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rightside);

        v.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv1.setText(text1[position]);
    holder.tv2.setText(text2[position]);

    return v;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
01-04 09:26:54.912 18405-18405/app.example.app.example.app.flavor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.example.app.example.myapp.flavor, PID: 18405
java.lang.NullPointerException
at app.example.myapp.Adapter.getView(Adapter.java:74)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1037)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:747)
at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1156)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @CodingRat I posted logs

Answer (score 1):

Preprocess your array deleting those rows (the null ones) that you don't want to show by creating a new list. Then pass that list to your array instead of the original one.

Comment: For certain reasons I can't do that. I need it to hide the entire row if a value in either array is null.

Comment: @DanielChambers how comes? If you explain why, it could help posters answer your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @ataulm So the left value in the `listView` comes from an `array` of 4 items that repeat (they are `concatenated` in a `for loop`), and the right value corresponds with each of those (left) values. So if the right value is removed, it will mess up the whole order of the data.

Comment: I would edit your question posting the data structure(s) and where you set it/update the data structure onto your adapter. @guillermo's answer will be applicable, it's just a case of identifying where best to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewGroup parameter can't be null. Just pass in the ViewGroup argument provided in the getview method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Holder holder;
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new Holder();

        if (text2[position] != null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailrow, null);
        } else {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.null_row, null);
        }

        if (text2[position] != null) {
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.leftside);
        } else {
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rightside);
        }

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
    }

    if (text2[position] != null) {
        holder.tv1.setText(text2[position]);
    } else {
        holder.tv2.setText("N/A");
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: I still get a NullPointerException on Line 75: holder.tv2.setText(text2[position]);

Comment: @Daniel Chambers, check `if`, change `==` instead of `!=`. You put `null` as text, you should not do that.

Comment: If I make the text "N/A" instead would it work better?

Comment: @Daniel Chambers, I have updated my answer. if you want to set text that should not be changed in future, you better put it in `strings.xml` like this

<string name="no_result">N/A</string>